# Building Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: visual-studio-2013, protocol-buffers

I'm having trouble building Google Protocol Buffer 2.5.0 in VS2013.

Specifically, when migrating the code to VS2013, the report generated tells me that `gtest.vcproj` and `gtest_main.vcproj` are missing.

On the off-chance that this was a fluke, I tried building this solution and received ~85 "File not found" errors regarding files in "`\src\google\protobuf\...`"

Am I actually missing projects? If so, why does the downloadable from the Google Protocol Buffers project not contain everything? If not, what else is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

These files are included in the zip (I had different errors though); you can try to download it again and upgrade project again.

Upgrade report showed only warnings for me. I had two kind of errors while compiling: min/max not found and cannot open pdb. Both mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=531 with solutions (include  and use /FS flag respectively).

BTW try to open the zip without extracting and see if these are here. Maybe something deleted them after extraction? Antivirus, sync client?